# Why is my IsolatedStorage whiped when I rebuild my Windows Phone 8 project?

Tags: windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013, isolatedstorage

There are several questions on StackOverflow about the same topic, but I haven't found the solution.

In my Windows Phone 8 App I store user settings in the `IsolatedStorage.ApplicationSettings`.
This works great, I use `IsolatedStorage.ApplicationSettings[key] = value` to set my values and ofcourse use `IsolatedStorage.ApplicationSettings.Save()` to save them.
I have also created a database using a .sdf file to save local data.

When I use the `Deploy` function in VS2013(Visual Studio 2013) to update my app, the isolated storage settings will remain.

However, when I have used the `Rebuild` or `Clean` function in VS2013, the isolated storage will be whiped on the next deploy! Resulting in the deletion of all local data and usersettings.

Why does this behavior occur?

A work-around would be to not use these functions, I could basically do all my work from development to deployment without using `Rebuild` or `Clean`. But when I would (accidentally) use these functions I would be unable to deploy without whiping all local data on the devices.

This behavior also occurs when I upload my App to the Windows Phone Beta Store. (I haven't used the live store yet)

UPDATE:

Thanks to robwirving I have some new insight: `XapDeployCmd.exe`

This is a tool that can perform all the deployment tasks that Visual Studio normally does for you, in command prompt. The relevant actions are `installlaunch` and `update`.

I think VS performs an `installlaunch` action when the deployment process detects the project has been rebuild. However, if I use the `update` action with XapDeployCmd on a Xap build by Visual Studio, which has been `Cleaned` and `Rebuild`, the isolated storage is NOT whiped.

Could it be that the Windows Phone Beta Store mimics this behavior?

Answer (score 2):

The default behavior of Visual Studio is to do a fresh install instead of an update when it has detected a rebuild. As far as I know this is not configurable.

You could do a rebuild and then update your XAP without deploying through Visual Studio however. Here is the documentation for XapDeployCmd, a command line tool included in the Windows Phone Dev tools that allows you to install or update a XAP from the command line. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff402565%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your reply! But my main problem is that the Isolated Storage is whiped when my testers download the App from the Beta store when I did a rebuild of the project. I've also tried using XapDeployCmd, this give me insight on how Visual Studio performs the updates! I've updated my question with this new insight.

Comment: That is interesting. I wouldn't expect the beta store to wipe storage after a clean/rebuild-ed xap was posted. I'm going to create a test app myself and try to investigate this further.

Comment: Did you get any results yet Robwirving?

Answer (score 1):

When You perform `Clean` Solution Visual Studio Cleans all the data related to Project and all related linking to the `.dlls` and other `linked data`. It serves as cleaning of all Generated files and data so Ultimately you loss your local data.

In the Case of `Rebuild` Solution Visual Studio `Regenerates` files and data that you are using with that Solution so In the Process of Regenerating your `data` and linking of `.dlls` also get cleared and new solution for that Project is Created so here you also loss Your data

In Short, The Process of `Clean` Cleans the Whole Solution linking and data while `Rebuild` regenrates the new solution after cleaning the data and linkings.

Comment: This is just an explanation of clean\rebuild. Doesn't answer anything to do with Isolated Storage on Windows Phone.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However, as Rob stated, this does not answer my question on why the Isolated Storage is whiped.

Comment: as mentioned above rebuild/Clean cleans all data that include isolatedstorage storage for your app too

Comment: A rebuild/clean is performed in Visual Studio. This process does not whipe the isolated storage. This happens when the Xap is deployed on the phone.

Comment: Thats right but ultimately when Rebuilded/cleaned .xap file would be installed in your device or emulator it gets new Isolated storage for new Xap so your old data and old .xap file is deleted.

Comment: This seems to be the case indeed, however, in a live scenario this should never occur, right? And in a test scenario, I'd like to see that the isolated storage settings would not be whiped, so any potential problems with (old) settigns would arise while beta-testing